# Are protein shakes healthy and safe?

Tags: protein, protein-shakes

Are protein shakes healthy and safe? Because they look as medicine to me. Powder that you mix with water. This seems un-natural like pills or so. I'm actually very hesitant to use them, so I'm thinking to only use natural food that are rich in protein like tuna or chicken breasts. What do you think?

Comment: Several previous questions on protein shakes may help: [Are there health risks](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7873/are-there-health-risks-associated-with-protein-shakes), [Protein shakes and kidneys](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14408/do-protein-shakes-really-damage-the-kidneys/16202#16202), [How to choose](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3671/how-to-choose-the-right-protein-shake), [Beginner](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5727/which-protein-shake-i-should-take-as-a-beginner)

Answer (score 2):

I felt the same way when I started to drink protein. I wasn't sure if it was safe or effective to use these supplements. I actually consulted my doctor regarding them and she said that used in moderation there is no health risk for them unless you are allergic to the ingredients. That was about a year and a half ago, and now every time I finish a workout I will drink a single shake with usually 60 grams of protein in it. Very often whey protein is used to help build lean muscle or mass. If you are really concerned about using these products, there are all natural protein mixes out there that can be combined with fruit or vegetables to make shakes with the same amount of protein. Blender Bottle has a whole list of different shakes that all for whey protein with natural things such as yogurt or fruit:
http://www.blenderbottle.com/recipe/protein-shake-recipes/